# Why is the first value of the array being replaced?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, dynamic

I don't understand why the first value of my array is changed outside the inner while loop when the "i" increments correctly. Am I allocating memory in a way that messes something up? How do I go about correcting this issue?

```
int main(void) 
{
  int sizeArray = 5, sizeString = 10;
  FILE *fin = fopen("file.txt", "r");
  char ** arr = (char **) malloc(sizeArray * sizeof(char *));
  char line[1000];
  char *word;
  int i = 0;
  while(fgets(line, 100, fin) != NULL)
  {
    word = strtok(line, " ");
    while (i < 2)
    {
      arr[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeString * sizeof(char));
      arr[i] = word;
      printf("Inner print: %s\n\n",arr[0]);
      word = strtok(NULL, " ");
      i++;
    }

  }
    printf("This is the final arr[0] (outer print): %s",arr[0]);

}
```

file.txt reads as:

```
First second.
Third! Fourth
```

The print from my console is as follows:

```
Inner print: First

Inner print: First

The final arr[0] (outer print): Third!
```

When I want the outer print to be: First

Comment: `arr[i] = word;` Probably doesn't do what you want. Use `strcpy` to copy strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You allocate some memory with `arr[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeString * sizeof(char));`.  You then immediately overwrite that pointer (leaking the memory) with `arr[i] = word`, so that `arr[i]` now points somewhere in the `line` buffer.

You need to copy the string pointed to by `word` into the buffer allocated for `arr[i]`:

```
strcpy_s(arr[i], sizeString * sizeof(char), word);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move `int i = 0;` inside the outer while loop. Or to the very least reset it to zero when the inner loop is done.

`arr[i] = word` is not how you copy strings in C. Have a look at `strcpy`, or even better, `strncpy`.

Performing `arr[i] = word` right after you have done `arr[i] = (char *)malloc` makes the `malloc` completely useless. The ONLY thing this accomplishes is to allocate space and then throw the pointer away, yielding a memory leak.